# Reloading UICollectionview from subview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, reload

I invoke a full screen subview from one of my uicollectionviewcells. This subview adds new cells to the collectionview. Before I remove this subview itself from its superview (uicollectionview) I call update function from the subview itself in uicollectionviewcontroller as below,

```
func update() {
   self.uicollectionview?.reloadData()
}
```

But nothing happens until I kill the app and reopen it. I also used dequeue async. But nothing changes. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thnx,

Update 1:

I call below method from my subview. After some animations, subview removes itself from the superview and calls update function in superview controller. I also swapped the lines and put removeFromSubview method as the last call. But it did not worked.

```
    func tapHandler(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    if sender?.state == .ended {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .transitionCurlDown, animations: {
            self.recordButton.frame = CGRect(origin: self.recordButton.center, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
            self.timerLabel.frame = CGRect(origin: self.timerLabel.center, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
            self.circularProgressBar.frame = CGRect(origin: self.circularProgressBar.center, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))

        }, completion: { (completed) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .transitionCurlDown, animations: {
                self.recorderView.frame = CGRect(origin: self.recorderView.center, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
                self.blurEffectView.effect = nil
            }, completion: { (animationCompleted) in


                self.removeFromSuperview()

                print("I am finished")
                let hdsc = HomeDatasourceController()
                hdsc.update()


            })
        })
    }
}
```

the update method in superview controller is as below

```
    func update() {
    print("update() func called")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
```

Also the subview is defined as a weak var in superview controller as

```
weak var audioPlayerView: AudioPlayerView?
weak var audioRecorderView: AudioRecorderView?
```

Comment: is update being called on main thread ? is uiCollectionView reference is non nil

Comment: replace line `self.uicollectionview!.reloadData()`  If this is nil it will crash.

Comment: Then you can figure out the problem

Comment: So I tested your code, and while this condition is true : if sender?.state == .ended it works, your collectionview is not reloading due to this code...:     
    let hdsc = HomeDatasourceController()
    hdsc.update() ....it looks strange what does  HomeDatasourceController() do, beacause here you should call update on an already existing collectionview, are you creating it ..with that code ?

Comment: homedatasource Controller is the collectionview controller (the main controller of the app).  I make the instance of homedata sourcecontroller in my recorder subview to call the update() function in homedatasourcecontroller. When I call update I see the viewdidload of homedatasourcecontroller is called. May be you are right, maybe I cannot address already existing homedatasourcecontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question. I forgot to mention that I was using LBTA components API for my collection view. I just reset my datasource once again in update function after I added new objects to the datasource and now it functions.

```
    func update() {
    print("update() func called")
    let hds = HomeDataSource()
    self.datasource = hds
    collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

but it is strange, I was expecting that reloadData() function would do it for me... Thanks to all who helped me through out...

Answer (score 0):

Try dispatching the reload on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ [weak self] in
    self?.uicollectionview?.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: I will try this one when I am back home and give a feedback to you all. Thanks for now and it is incredible how fast I got some anwers!..

Comment: the updated version of above code is, `DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        } `    and it did not work. :(

Comment: Ok, so now we will need more code from you in order to help you, show us the method in which you add more cells. I'm now thinking that if you are inserting cells you do not need reload.

Comment: I added an update. I hope I could explain the problem. Thnx.